# React native - show the webpage inside the apps

Tags: react-native

I'm developing an social apps whereby user can simply attach a website URL, and when other user click on it it will show a webpage within the apps.

For example as below 
[image]

I'm using react navigation, is there a way can achieve this ?

Comment: Didn't webview  worked for you? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### RN > 0.59

Use [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview).

Use `WebView`.

Example from [official link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview#usage).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

It will be better use `WebView` in your component having header and basic control as backbutton and closebutton.